# How to delete all row which contains “Delete” in Excel automatically in ALL the sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I have different Sheets called :

> "Champagne"
>        "Water"
>        "ChocoStrawb"
>        "Bronze"
>        "Silver"
>        "Gold"
>        "Platinum"
>        "PlPlus"
>        "Ambassador"

I have this code :

```
Sheets("water").Select
Dim rng As Range, cell_search As Range, del As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Range("A2:A4200"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
For Each cell_search In rng
    If (cell_search.Value) = "Delete" Then
        If del Is Nothing Then
            Set del = cell_search
        Else: Set del = Union(del, cell_search)
    End If
End If
Next cell_search
On Error Resume Next
del.EntireRow.Delete
```

But It delete the row only in the sheet "Water" I want this to be effective in all sheets.

Comment: @0m3r The column A has the delete Value. so If it is written in the column A "Delete" I would like the row to be erased completely.

Comment: well I see you got your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a macro that runs through each worksheet in your workbook:

```
Sub AllWorkbooks()
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For x = 4200 To 2 Step -1
        If WS.Cells(x, 1).Value = "Delete" Then
            WS.Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next x
Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: I don t want to create an another Sub.. Everything needs to be on the same macro... do you have something ...

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO.... Thank you so much ...... I have One more question for you.. It is about my macro as well but it is more complicated this time... Could you help me ?

Comment: No worries, what is your question?

Comment: I have an other Question "How to align duplicates on the same rows in Excel in VBA" can you check if you can do something please...

Answer (score 0):

`Autofilter()` will speed things up

you can start by a Sub that "handles" a passed `worksheet` object:

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithKeyword(sht As Worksheet, keyWord As String)
    With sht '<--| reference passed sht
        With .Range("A1", .cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A range form row 1 (header) down to its last not empty row
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=keyWord '<--| filter cells with passed 'keyWord'
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete  '<--| if any filtered cells other than header then delete their entore row
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

and then you can have your "Main" sub exploit it

- loop through ALL worksheets

  ```
  Sub Main()
      Dim sht As Worksheet

      For Each sht In Worksheets
          DeleteRowsWithKeyword sht, "Delete"
      Next
  End Sub
  ```
- loop through all sheets with given names:

  ```
  Sub Main()
      Dim sheetNames As Variant, shtName As Variant

      sheetNames = Array("Champagne", "Water", "ChocoStrawb", "Bronze", "Silver", "Gold", "Platinum", "PlPlus", "Ambassador") '<--| list all your relevant sheet names here
      For Each shtName In sheetNames
          DeleteRowsWithKeyword Sheets(shtName), "Delete"
      Next
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: @JohanEs, if my answer solves your question then please accept it by   clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you

Comment: Is it possible put everything on the same Sub.. I don't want to run several Macro. Everything needs to be on the same run.. How should I put it ?? .... please

Comment: You put both DeleteRowsWithKeyword() sub and the Main() sub of your choice (choose the one that matches your looping needs) in the same module and just run the latter.